# tradeoffs number of class vs readability

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web-applications

We a team are developing a social networking site.

We are following the multi-tier application structure, i.e we have written webserivces(REST) (which is common in these days), and developing several clients for the same.

As we have written REST webservice that needs to be exposed, and API doc must be created for the same, so that if anyone is developing any client application must be able to get the clear idea of what service takes what kinda input (JSON) and returns what kinda output (JSON).

We are using Spring based RESTful webservices which will convert the objects to JSON representation and JSON to object using the respective MessageConvertors.

**My Concern:**

**Readable:** To make the exposed webservices more readable to the one developing clients, we must have different input/output types(i.e, different classes for each kind of requests/responses), so that the API generated will clearly tell what kind of json input is expected by a particular service and what is the output json for that.

**Number of classes:** As we go on creating different classes for each request and response types the number of classes will increase and hence at the run time more number of classes will be loaded, we are getting permgen: OutOfMemoryException (not sure it is because of more no of classes).

What is the way out for this?

What is the best optimized way of handling this?

I am new to web application development and not a professional so not sure which is the best way.

Comment: I doubt very much that number of classes is a cause for `OutOfMemoryException`s (unless you are running on a 64k machine :-P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't **have** to have different classes to represent the different inputs and outputs, as long as it is clearly documented what the structure is, it can be reused many times.

Unless you literally thousands of webservices with massively complex inputs/outputs and running on a tiny VM, the permgen error is likely not due to that.

I assume that spring uses annotations like JAX-RS for rest services in which case you can generate the documentation based on that.

As a sidenote: a REST-based interface is always a good thing to have, but I would suggest supporting both JSON and XML. The former is interesting for websites while the latter is interesting for well...anything else.